# How to load hive orc partitioned to Hbase table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, cloudera, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm completely beginning into hbase data store, we are currently migrating hive external file system with orc file format. Past 2 years data needs to move to hbase tables, i seen few of bulkload approach hcatalog and pig using but not orc file format. Can you please help me out or give me some suggestion on this issue. Here i mentioned hive table schema structure also;

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE countTbl (
 client_id bigint,
 count1 bigint,
 inserted_at bigint,
count2 bigint,
 date_time bigint,
id_dic STRUCT<id1:array<STRING>,id2:array<BIGINT>>,
 partition_date string
)
partitioned by (primaryid string)
stored as orc
LOCATION 'hdfs://user/hadoop/countTbl';
```

Answer (score 0):

hbase support only simple datatype, your hive table field `id_dic` should be simplified to store into hfile
you can use hive table project to hbase or bulkload into hbase